# Is there any way to add delay on button action to happen by generic way? i.e from custom class of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom class of UIButton. I want to add delay on action if user tap on button. I can use following code to each and every button action but I want to use generic solution so that I need not to visit each and every button action places.

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4, execute: {
            // do action
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can add more details here? cant get the idea what you are trying here and what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the action in to the custom class as a closure. You then just need to link the IBAction up in storyboard or you can do programatically in the button init with addTarget if not using storyboard. I assume you have an init in your custom class setting up other properties on the button.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    var buttonAction: () -> Void
    
    init(frame: CGRect , _ buttonAction: @escaping () -> Void ) {
        self.buttonAction = buttonAction
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // This code below passes the action in if you are not using @IBAction / Storyboard
        // self.addTarget(self , action: #selector(delayTapAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        delayTapAction()
    }
    
    @objc func delayTapAction() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4, execute: {
            self.buttonAction()
            print("Action Ran!")
        })
    }
    
}
```

Calling programatically you can pass the action in as a closure as follows. Be wary if you are running logic that may capture the view controller self and use weak or unowned if actions could run a more than a short response in async.

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let button = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 32)) {
            print("Action prints after delay")
        }
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather generic way is to use Combine.

- Implement an extension of `UIControl` described in the Medium article [**Observe UIButton Events Using Combine in Swift 5**](https://betterprogramming.pub/observe-uibutton-events-using-combine-in-swift-5-63c1a4e0a0c1) to be able to observe any button event, the full code is available on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/zafarivaev/d5864857cd18bc21982a066396368c6a).
- Add this extension of `UIButton`, the `delay` operator does what its name implies.

  ```
  extension UIButton {
       var tapDelayPublisher : AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
          return self
               .publisher(for: .touchUpInside)
               .delay(for: .milliseconds(400), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
               .eraseToAnyPublisher()
       }
  }
  ```
- Observe the button(s)

  ```
  var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  // ...
  button.tapDelayPublisher
      .sink { _ in
          print("Button tapped)
      }
      .store(in: &subscriptions)
  ```